# Camera feed sent through TCP socket gets stuck sometimes

Tags: python, picamera, sockets

I am getting the camera feed from a camera on a Raspberry PI to the computer using a TCP socket to use it for openCV. It works well with minimal delay. However, sometimes the frame gets stuck(freeze) and after a while the feed gets back or the openCV window crashes. I have looked everywhere and tried multiple things, but I just don't know what is causing it.

Server (PC):

```
import socket
import struct
import numpy as np
import cv2

host = "192.168.0.12"
portCar = 8010

# Camera socket
camS = socket.socket()
camS.bind((host, portCar))

camS.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

# Listen for camera
camS.listen(0)
print("Waiting for camera connection...")

camCon = camS.accept()[0]
camFile = camCon.makefile("rb")
print("Connection made with camera")

camS.settimeout(0.00001)

numOfBytes = struct.calcsize("<L")

try:
    while(True):
        camS.setblocking(False)

        imageLength = struct.unpack("<L", camFile.read(numOfBytes))[0]    

        if imageLength == 0:
            break

        nparr = np.frombuffer(camFile.read(imageLength), np.uint8)
        frame = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        cv2.imshow('RC Car Video stream', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

finally:
    camFile.close()
    camS.close()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Server - Camera connection closed")
```

Client (PI):

```
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera

client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('192.168.0.12', 8010))

client_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

class SplitFrames(object):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.stream = io.BytesIO()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            size = self.stream.tell()
            if size > 0:
                self.connection.write(struct.pack('<L', size))
                self.connection.flush()
                self.stream.seek(0)
                self.connection.write(self.stream.read(size))
                self.stream.seek(0)

        self.stream.write(buf)


try:
    output = SplitFrames(connection)
    with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='VGA', framerate=30) as camera:
        time.sleep(2)
        camera.rotation = 180
        camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
        camera.wait_recording(2000)
        camera.stop_recording()
        # Write the terminating 0-length to the connection to let the
        # server know we're done
        connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
    print("Client - Connection closed")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "have looked everywhere and tried multiple things" - any details on that would be helpful.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev As you can see from the code I am trying to use .settimeout(0.00001) and I tried catching that after .read(). That did not work. I also tried using select, I either did that wrong or it did not work. I also am setting to non blocking mode. That did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any TCP errors or retransmissions on the active network interface? It may be that your connection is so poor that TCP ends up losig data and then your program crashes since there's no code handling data loss. Check out the output of `netstat -s | grep retransmitted` and `ifconfig | grep error` some time after activating the network interface (ideally, after a crash) to confirm.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It doesn't really crash. When it gets "stuck", the window says "Not responding" and then if I leave to for a while, about 5-10 seconds, the camera feed will come again after skipping(speed) through the frames it missed.

Comment: I did run the netstat -s | grep retransmitted and got 335 segments retransmitted.

Comment: RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

That is the output of the ifconfig | grep error command

Comment: Hello. Just wondering if you have any more questions or you think what is wrong.

Comment: @RinoLeonardino No, sorry. Debugging this in person could already be a challenge, not to say about remotely guessing what could be wrong.